# How to create dynamic sql string according to unknown column count

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I think the title is clearly. There is a sqlite app in android. The app is when starts, it's creates a database and tables. But the **tables, columns, types, column count** absolutely not specific. So, I need to create a perfect dynamic structure. I will take **columns, tables, types** and anything of about database from a xml. That is the point, the xml...

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a(" + col_parameter1 +" " type_paramater1+","+ ... col_paramaterN + " " + type_parameterN +")" ;
```

I dont know how many creates table, how many colunms. I do try too way but all of them not perfect.

Comment: From what I understand correctly, there is an xml file which has the list of table columns and the corresponding data types to be created in the table.
Can you not just iterate over the xml and get a hold of that informaiton and do Java String append?.

Comment: Bro, actually i have tried string builder. But not whit array. Now, i will try again with a loop with string array. I'll add comment the result. thank you. just may be there is more effective way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it will help you

```
class Column {
    String name;
    String type;
}

public class Main{

//Fill colums with data read from xml

 public String createTableQuery(List<Column> colums){
        StringBuffer  query = new StringBuffer();
        query.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a(") ;
        for(int i = 0; i < colums.size(); i++){
            Column col = colums.get(i);
            query.append(" " + col.name + " " +col.type + ", ");
        }
        query.append(")");

        return query.toString();
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that is gave to me an idea. I will edit. I do just a String array like this ; String a = { "id", "integer", "name", "text"...}. i think it will enough.

Comment: instead of  List<Colum> columns 
you can do   Map<String, String> columns. 

And add you values to it